# Pre-fill PHP field with free text

Tags: php

I have a PHP form and need to pre-fill one of the fields with some static free text, for this exercise let's call it "MYTEXT".

```
if (preg_match ('/^[A-Z \'.-]{2,40}$/i', $trimmed['jobtitle'])) 
    {
        $jt = mysqli_real_escape_string ($dbc, $trimmed['jobtitle']);
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo '<p style="font-weight: bold; color: #C00">Please enter where you heard about us!</p>';
    }
```

And the form:

```
<tr>
    <td class="single-field-left">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="jobtitle">Your job title<em class="red">* </em></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input class="input-text" name="jobtitle" title="jobtitle" type="text" value="<?php if (isset($trimmed['jobtitle'])) echo $trimmed['jobtitle']; ?>" id="jobtitle" />
                </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Instead of the input box being empty I need it to have "MYTEXT" in the field as soon as the page loads. It needs to be actual text, not just a placeholder.

I'm a PHP novice so guidance appreciated

Comment: A little confused about your question, so you wanted the input to have a default value? Use a `placeholder`

Comment: Question updated. A placeholder won't be suitable as I need it to be actual text

Comment: ..is `MYTEXT` stored in `$trimmed['jobtitle']`? Is [this your desired output](https://jsfiddle.net/zo16fkdy/)?

Comment: Tried your code, everything works fine here. Most probably, $trimmed['jobtitle'] is empty at the time that the form is displayed. Check out the PHP code where you set $trimmed['jobtitle']

Comment: Or just use an `if` statement in the value attribute. To tell if the form has been set or not; If not, then show default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input class="input-text" name="jobtitle" title="jobtitle" type="text" value="MYTEXT" id="jobtitle" />
```

Thanks to hd for the answer

[HD's fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zo16fkdy/)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not that much clear. Anyways i think your value is stored in the variable $jt. Try the code below :)

```
   <input class="input-text" name="jobtitle" title="jobtitle" type="text" value="<?php if (isset($jt)){ echo $jt; }else{echo "";} ?>" id="jobtitle" />
```